# Need help in creating tcolorbox (like the one in manual)

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox

I am trying to create a tcolorbox like the one mentioned in version 3.40 manual:

[image]

I tried to figure out the settings by going through the source code, available here:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox

Till now, I am not able to create a MWE using the extracted settings but it seems that they are too complicated to just draw a box:

```
  \documentclass[10pt]{book}

  \def\tcb@layer@pushup{%
  \tcb@count@boxes%
  \global\advance\tcolorbox@number by -1\relax%
  \stepcounter{tcblayer}%
  \ifnum\c@tcblayer>1%
    \tcbset{breakable@true/.code=}%
  \else%
    \ifinner\ifhmode\tcbset{breakable@true/.code=}\fi\fi%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\c@tcblayer>\tcb@managed@layers@max%
    \tcbset{every box on higher layers}%
    \tcbset{every box on higher layers/.code=}%
  \else%
    \tcbset{every box on layer \number\c@tcblayer}%
    \tcbset{every box on layer \number\c@tcblayer/.code=}%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{tcblayer}{-1}%
}

\tcbset{
  docexample/.style={colframe=ExampleFrame,colback=ExampleBack,
    before skip=\medskipamount,after skip=\medskipamount,
    fontlower=\footnotesize},
  index default settings/.style={index actual={@},index quote={"},index level={!}},
  index german settings/.style={index actual={=},index quote={!},index level={>}},
  english language/.code={\tcbset{doclang/.cd,
    color=color,colors=Colors,
    counter=counter,counters=Counters,
    environment content=environment content,
    environment=environment,environments=Environments,
    index=Index,
    key=key,keys=Keys,
    length=length,lengths=Lengths,
    new=New,
    pageshort={P.},
    updated=Updated,
    value=value,values=Values}},
}

 \def\dispListing{\tcb@layer@pushup\tcbset{docexample}\begingroup\tcbwritetemp}

\def\enddispListing{%
  \endtcbwritetemp\endgroup%
  \begin{tcolorbox}%
  \tcb@doc@usetemplisting%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{dispListing}
Hello World
\end{dispListing}
```

Can someone please suggest me a simpler way to draw a similar box ?

Comment: You could at least have provided a `\documentclass` etc :-( -- and current version of `tcolorbox` is 3.93 already

Comment: No, it's still not compilable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default` code boxes for `tcolorbox`version 3.40 are different from last version 3.93. I don't know how to obtain 3.40 code to dive into, so I've tried to do something similar. Hope it helps.

OP box has a frame based on a fixed image which looks like a rotated version of  `blueshade.png` from `tcolorbox`.

[image]

As I don't know how to rotate it being the `frame style image`, the result is not the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=blue!25!black!15, enhanced, frame style image=blueshade.png, drop fuzzy shadow}

\begin{mybox}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

*Update*

Thank you to Christian Hupfer who provided a link to 3.40 version, I could find how default code boxes were defined. In this case, `svgnames` option must be passed to `xcolor` and `all` option to `tcolorbox` because `ExampleBack` color is defined in its `documentation` library:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=Navy!5!ExampleBack, enhanced, 
    frame style ={fill stretch image*={angle=180,origin=c}{blueshade.png},         
          fill image opacity=0.75}, 
    drop fuzzy shadow}

\begin{mybox}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You will find 3.40 here: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/releases?after=v3.61